# CSS border - how to populate content inside div with border

Tags: html, css

I have
[this](http://i45.tinypic.com/2prvkg9.png):

Now, I want two things... Left div (navigation) I want border all the way to the bottom.
Second, I want content inside #content div and footer must be after it.

Why does the content go allway to the content and footer?

Thank you.

EDIT:

CSS:

```
 #header { padding: 0px; color: #000; background: #fff;}
  #topnav { color: #aaa; background: transparent; position: inherit;}
  #main { margin: 10px 0; background: #fff;  height: 50%;}
  #footer { padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px; margin-top: 25px; color:#666; background: #f9f9f9; border-top: 5px #efefef solid; }

  #col1 { float: left; width: 13%;}
  #col2 { display:none}
  #col3 { width: auto; margin: 0 0 0 15%}
  #col1_content { padding: 0 10px 0 20px;}
  #col3_content { padding: 0 20px 0 10px;}
  #col1 { border-right: 5px #ddd ridge }
```

Comment: can you show your css or html instead of a png? but it looks like you float the left div and the two other divs on the right aren't floated so they topple each other.

Comment: oh and since the content of the left div is only a few items when you give a border-right it doesn't go all the way down. instead you can give the main div on the right border-left so the line will go all the way down

Comment: @Mutu, I did this with border and it works great. Thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't give you "like" on your comment... Don't have enough reputation.

Comment: it's okay, glad to have helped

Comment: Thank you. I've added my CSS so please help me with content going over footer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

place your footer with absolute positioning so it gets anchored to the very bottom like all footers should be unless you have something different in mind.

```
#footer { position:absolute; bottom: 0px; left: 0px; }
```